# Admin notice on wp_insert_post

Tags: posts, hooks, errors, wp-insert-post, notifications

I am trying to display some error messages in case some conditions are not met when using wp_insert_post. However, it the admin_notice doesn't seem to trigger.

Here's the example I have:

```
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'automate_intercom', 10, 3);
    function automate_intercom($post_id, $post, $update) {

        if($post->post_status == 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'help-center') {
            
            $someCondition = '';

            if($someCondition!== '') {

            }else{
                add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_example_error' );


            }


        }
    }

    function show_example_error() {
        $class = 'notice notice-info';
        $message = __( 'Example error', 'admin_notice' );
        error_log("In admin notice ");
    printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), $message); 
    }
```

Any ideas why it doesn't trigger the admin_notices?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks cannot be added directly inside functions. Using [do_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/), you can invoke a custom hook.

In your case try out the below solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'automate_intercom', 10, 3 );
function automate_intercom( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( $post->post_status == 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'help-center' ) {

        $someCondition = '';

        if ( $someCondition !== '' ) {

        } else {
            show_example_error();
        }
    }
}

function show_example_error() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->post_type == 'help-center' ) {
        $class   = 'notice notice-info';
        $message = __( 'Example error', 'admin_notice' );
        error_log( 'In admin notice ' );
        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), $message );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_example_error' );
```

Comment: which one should be do_action?

Comment: When you have a custom hook then you can use do_action but right now you can try out the above solution. Just call `show_example_error()` function when your conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: oh it does work, but i just realized that the admin notice is hidden during post publish/updating. Is there any way I could make this display or should I look into another solution?

Comment: But you have given the condition that post_status->publish after that it will call function. So it will show after your post published

Comment: shouldnt it show during the publishing/updating process? right now it only shows here: https://freeimage.host/i/HYcLYTG

Comment: Yes, that will be shown here.

Comment: Ok, so to display it during the creation of a post(when updating/publishing), what approach should I take?

Comment: Afterwards, I'll do that in my local and let you know

Comment: ok let me know if you have a hint for this